# R code. write a floor function

Tags: r, function

I want to write a floor function in R, which returns a floating number to its nearest integer. So I tried the below function. It seems that it works if I assign a value to x and run the code inside the function, but it fails when I try to put everything in a function and call the function name later.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks!

```
> my_floor <- function(x) {
    x <- x-0.5
    as.integer(x)
    return (x)
 }

> y <- 3.1052255
> my_floor(y)  
[1] 2.605225
```

Comment: To fix the return value, you need to either assign `as.integer(x)` to a variable, or do `return(as.integer(x))` or simply remove the last line so that the last line becomes `as.integer(x)`

Comment: ...and even then I'm not sure it will always do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's a different story

Comment: You say you want to implement a `floor` function. Than you say you want to return the nearest integer, which is what `round` does. You need to clarify this. `as.numeric(as.integer(x) - ((x %% 1) != 0L & sign(x) == -1L))` should return the same result as `floor`.

Comment: `round` with a second argument of 0 (which is the default so just `round (x)` succeeds) will do what was requested, but that is not what "floor" does in other languages. The R equivalent of 'floor' is `trunc`

Comment: @BondedDust I would say `floor` is the R equivalent of 'floor'.

Comment: I stand (or sit) corrected.

Answer (score 0):

No very sure what you are trying to do but if you simply want the input transformed to the nearest integer towards zero (i.e. **floored** as you your question goes), the one way to do it would be:

`my_floor <- function(x) {
  x <- trunc(x)
  return (x)
 }`

This simply discards the non integer part of your input using R's `trunc`: which you might as well call directly i.e. `trunc(y)` will still give you the desired result. If you wish to use your function above "as is" then:

`my_floor <- function(x) {
   x <- x-0.5
   x <- as.integer(x) #Store the result of this second step by reassigning x
   return (x)
 }`

Comment: I think OP was interested in coding an algorithm for `floor`. This answer, `my_floor <- trunc`, is essentially equivalent to `my_floor <- floor`, which seems to defeat any purpose.

Comment: Indeed. And I just saw that the second suggestion is already mentioned in a comment by RS.